# Wordpress Menu hickup

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

At the moment i am converting my HTML to Wordpress. No matter what i try i can't seem to get my menu look the same in
Wordpress as it does in HTML. The CSS is correct (did allot of troubleshooting to root that out). This is the HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only"> Toggle navigation </span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="assets/img/Logo%20BY.png" alt="Logo" height="75" width="75"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="onzediensten.html">Onze diensten</a></li>
          <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Good header]

And this is the Wordpress way i am trying to implement:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only"> Toggle navigation </span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
          <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/Logo%20BY.png" alt="Logo" height="75" width="75">
        </a>
      </div>
      <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
          'theme_location'  => 'primary',
          'container'       => 'nav',
          'container_class' => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
          'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
        )); 
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Faulty header]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Any updates on this? Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are missing the container div. Right click and inspect on the badly formatted menu and see if the (container) div is there

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

You have

```
'container'       => 'nav'
```

should be

```
'container'       => 'div'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but sadly it did not do the trick. Still got the issue i am afraid.

Comment: Did you right click and inspect to see what html is being produced by the php code and that it matches the html being replaced?